# Convertir las longitudes y latitudes en dato geométrico con Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

Necesito convertir las **longitudes y latitudes en dato geométrico (Geom)** con **Python**.
En **Sql** logre hacerlo de la siguiente forma, pero lo necesitaría en **Python**

```
geometry::STGeomFromText ('Point ('+cast(-58.4818916 as varchar)+' '+cast(-58.4118916 as varchar)+')',4326)
```

***Resultado***: 0xE6100000010CCA1BBB9FAE3D4DC0A1BF2BDDB8344DC0

Answer (score 2):

A la vista del resultado, que es un gran número escrito en hexadecimal, deduzco que el "dato geométrico" del que hablas debe de ser algún formato propietario de serialización binaria. Tras indagar un poco llego a la especificación de Microsoft siguiente ([disponible aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff624626(v=sql.105).aspx)):

- Los primeros 4 bytes son un identificador (SRID) que ha de ser 4326 para datos de tipo GEOGRAPHY, o bien 0 para los del tipo GEOMETRY (en tu caso pasas 4326, ¿está bien o debería ser cero?). Efectivamente podemos comprobar que las primeras ocho cifras del resultado (`E610000000`) son la representación *little endian* del dato 4326 (que en hexadecimal es `10E6`). Vamos bien.
- El siguiente byte es el número de versión. En tu resultado es `01`, que también tiene buena pinta.
- El siguiente byte (que en tu caso es `0C`) serían unos flags que en este caso particular se interpretan como 0C = 04 + 08, que implican "Geography is valid" y "Geography contains a single point". De nuevo tiene buena pinta.
- Los siguientes 8 bytes serían la representación binaria de un dato tipo *double*, y los 8 últimos otro dato tipo *double*. Estos datos son respectivamente la latitud y longitud del punto en cuestión.

¡Bien! Parece que hemos descifrado el formato binario en cuestión. Ahora necesitamos saber cómo generarlo desde python.

Para manipular datos en binario a tan bajo nivel, python proporciona el módulo `struct`, que permite empaquetar cualquier tipo de dato a una secuencia de bytes, especificando el formato binario que debe usarse. Esto dará como resultado un array de bytes. Para convertir el array de bytes a una representación ASCII legible (hexadecimal) podemos usar `binascii.hexlify`.

Juntando todo eso, tendríamos material para crear la siguiente función:

```
import struct
import binascii

def STGeomFromText(x, y, srid=4326):
    binario = struct.pack("<lbbdd", srid, 1, 0x0C, x, y)
    # El parámetro "<lbbdd" indica que el primer dato se codifique
    # como un entero largo (l) en orden little endian (<)
    # los dos siguientes en dos bytes (bb)
    # y los dos siguientes en dos doubles (dd)

    # Lo convertimos a cadena hexadecimal
    asciihex = binascii.hexlify(binario)

    # Y de hexadecimal a entero
    result = int(asciihex, 16)
    return result
```

Que usaríamos así, por ejemplo:

```
resultado = STGeomFromText(-58.4818916, -58.4118916, 4326)
```

El resultado es un entero largo. Si lo imprimimos sin más nos lo mostraría en base 10:

```
>>> print(resultado)
86076600432332322592911658947539051618412648549600704
```

Si queremos verlo en hexadecimal (y en mayúsculas para comparar con el que te sale a ti):

```
>>> print("0x%X" % resultado)
0xE6100000010CCA1BBB9FAE3D4DC0A1BF2BDDB8344DC0
```

¡Ha salido clavado! :-DD

Comment: Excelente!! voy a intentar esto! gracias