# Dato Geometrico

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy calculando a partir de la latitud/longitud el dato geometrico.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc280487(v=sql.120).aspx

```
consultaGeom = ('''select geometry::STGeomFromText('point('+left(?,12)+' '+left(?,12)+')' , 4326)''');
                 param = (latCIE,lngCIE)
                 query = ConexionProyecto.execute(consultaGeom,param)
                 row = query.fetchone()
                 print(row)
```

El inconveniente que el dato que devuelve la consulta y se muestra es

```
(b'\xe6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x0c\xbdR\x96!\x8e\xa5;\xc0\x1c\xeb\xe26\x1a\\P\xc0', )
```

Cuando deberia de ser

```
0xE6100000010C00000000004050C00000000000003CC0
```

Porque ocurre esto?

Necesito que el dato devuelto dea correcto para poder insertarlo en un campo geometrico.

Comment: Quizás relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/138548/7123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te retorna la función `fetchone()` es una tupla de un solo elemento. Extrayendo su primer elemento (`[0]`), obtienes una cadena de `bytes`, que puede convertirse a su representación hexadecimal con `bytes.hex()`.

Si necesitas que además esté exactamente como en el ejemplo que has mostrado (es decir, con un `0x` delante y los dígitos hexadecimales en mayúsculas), puedes usar `str.upper()` y concatenar el `0x`. Así:

```
consultaGeom = ('''select geometry::STGeomFromText('point('+left(?,12)+' '+left(?,12)+')' , 4326)''');
param = (latCIE,lngCIE)
query = ConexionProyecto.execute(consultaGeom,param)
row = query.fetchone()

row = "0x{}".format(row[0].hex().upper())
print(row)
```

> 0xE6100000010C00000000004050C00000000000003CC0

Comment: tengo el siguiente error al ejecutar el codigo 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'hex'

Comment: @Seba79 Ops, olvidé seleccionar el elemento 0. Actualizada la respuesta.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás recibiendo es un objeto de tipo `bytes`:

```
>>> type(b'\xe6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x0c\xbdR\x96!\x8e\xa5;\xc0\x1c\xeb\xe26\x1a\\P\xc0')
<class 'bytes'>
```

Por lo tanto, simplemente puedes llamar a su método [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

```
>>> b'\xe6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x0c\xbdR\x96!\x8e\xa5;\xc0\x1c\xeb\xe26\x1a\\P\xc0'.hex()
'e6100000010cbd5296218ea53bc01cebe2361a5c50c0'
```

También puedes usar [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/binascii.html):

```
>>> import binsacii
>>> hex_value = binascii.hexlify(b'\xe6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x0c\xbdR\x96!\x8e\xa5;\xc0\x1c\xeb\xe26\x1a\\P\xc0')
>>> hex_value
b'e6100000010cbd5296218ea53bc01cebe2361a5c50c0'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(hex_value)
b'\xe6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x0c\xbdR\x96!\x8e\xa5;\xc0\x1c\xeb\xe26\x1a\\P\xc0'
```